# Density plot for numerous variables using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to create a geom_point() plot for just y1 and y2 but I would like to be able to create a density plot that will allow me to use many (i'm using 5 y variable as an example but I will have up to 50 y variables)

This is some toy data i created as reference:

```
y1          y2          y3          y4          y5
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000100    0.000000    0.000100    0.000100    0.000000
0.000100    0.000100    0.000400    0.000200    0.000000
0.000100    0.000100    0.000400    0.000200    0.000100
0.000300    0.000100    0.000300    0.000200    0.000100
0.000300    0.000100    0.000000    0.000000    0.000300
0.000300    0.000100    0.000000    0.000200    0.000600
0.000400    0.000200    0.000100    0.000100    0.000500
0.000500    0.000100    0.000100    0.000100    0.000400
0.000500    0.000300    0.000100    0.000000    0.000700
0.000700    0.000400    0.000100    0.000300    0.000700
0.001100    0.000400    0.000100    0.000200    0.000900
```

Essentially, these values are the absolute value of change from the reference point (where clearly i used the first x value in the series as reference). I want to see the density (or a histogram with kernel smoothing) for the change in data where the x-values are the categories day 1, day 2, day 3, ... day 12.

Like i said, i think i want something like

```
setwd("null")
data <- read.table("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
n <- 5 # number of variables

for (i in 1:n) {
ggplot(data,aes(x=time, y = paste0("day.", i),color="grey"))
    +geom_density() + geom_density(aes(y = paste0("day.", i+1),color="grey"))
}
```

If someone could please help me it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot`s work best with data in long format.  So, reshaping data using `stack` allows easy separation of the density curves for each column.

```
dat <- stack(data)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=values, fill=ind)) + geom_density(alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

If you wanted to pass variable names to `aes` as in your `for` loop, use `aes_string` instead, ie

```
p <- ggplot(data)
for (n in names(data))
    p <- p + geom_density(aes_string(x=n))
```

But, this isn't nearly as good since its hard to apply aesthetics like colors, shapes, etc. to the different curves.

Comment: I dont understand what this shows. Would you mind explaining please? :)  I was kind of thinking it would be one density curve with day1, day2, day3.. on x axis and the absolute change on the y-axis(in all hoensty i dont really care what the y axis shows as long as i can visually understanad the graph)

Comment: @xionglui this is a density curve for each column in your data.  Density curves are like histograms, so you use them to examine a single variable.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, do you have a picture of a similar graphic?

Comment: x = values ? are those my day 1, day 2, day 3.. etc ? When i chart this i get all the y-values on the x axis.. id like to see the day 1, 2, 3 etc on x axis

Comment: I need the values across the x axis to be the categories day 1, day2, day3.. day 12. I want to visually see on what days the greatest changes were

Comment: @xionglui what you are describing is not a density plot.  are you looking for lines, bars, or what type of shape?

Comment: you could try `ggplot(dat, aes(ind, values)) + geom_point() + xlab("Day")`